# Choosing a "Home" page removes content on my Joomla site

Tags: jquery, joomla, joomla3.0

I'm having a bit of an odd issue. I'm using JoomlaShine's Boot template, and Joomla 3.0.1

Basically, the client wants featured articles to be on the website's home page. So I made a menu item which is set to -> Featured Articles. Here's the issue: When that item is set to "Home" (as my default page) for SOME reason that I can't figure out... All the content decides to become hidden or removed (although all the options and code say it's visible). If I pick another item to become the Home page, the Featured articles *original* desired home page link shows everything perfectly. But if I switch back... again, all the featured articles are removed.

> For visual aid, This is what the page looks like when it's set to
> "Home"
>
> *Image link removed - not enough rep*
>
> However, this is ACTUALLY how the page is configured, and when I pick
> another item to become the Home page this is how it looks:
>
> *Image link removed - not enough rep*
>
> ^^ The latter is the desired effect.

**EDIT~~**

**Alright I realised my method of posting images is not the most obvious. If you navigate to:**

http://new.providentia.org.uk/new/

**And then click on 'Home' in the navigation bar -- That's the difference between a page set to be the default homepage vs. what I've set it up to look like. Both setups are identical, it's just that for some reason choosing any page as the 'default' just removes all the content within it.**

**~~**

Really need a hand on this guys, Not sure what the issue is exactly but if you guys eed any code sinppets or anything else, please just ask and I'll provide asap! Thank you VERY much in advance

Comment: Go to the server tab of Global Configuration and set error reporting to Development. I suspect one of two things, either there is a module or plugin running only on that combination that is throwing an error or it could be that there is something special in the the template for the homepage. ALso, you're totally positive that you have some featured articles right?

Comment: @Elin Definitely! This is the website: http://new.providentia.org.uk/new/ <-- That's the homepage labeled Home2 but the ACTUAL homepage I'd like to use is called 'Home' if you go to that tab, you'll see what I want to be seeing. BTW, both tabs are identical - just that one of them is set to be the default page upon navigating to the site (home2 in this case)

Comment: @Elin I did as you asked, but I've received no errors. :S is that a good or a bad sign?

Comment: Can you try making the culture link the default page? Then we can see if it is a  problem anytime you make something default. Also, second test,  can you try assigning the default template to the menu link you want as default.

Comment: @Elin http://new.providentia.org.uk/new/index.php/2012-09-17-11-25-25.html --> Yep it messed up Culture aswell :/

Also, Everything's default to the JSNBoot template that I'm using so changing that made no difference. I think it's an issue with the template but again, I have no clue where things might have gone wrong as I haven't modified any files.

Comment: WHen you make a menu item you can assign the template, so just assign protostar to the default page.

Comment: @Elin Did that, and it worked! So given the current troubleshooting, what do you think is the issue?

Comment: I think your template has some special handling of the default page. http://demo.joomlashine.com/joomla-templates/jsn_boot/pro/index.php
is what their demo homepage looks like. On that page they offer downloadable documentation, maybe if you download it, it will explain what you need to do.

Comment: @Elin They have exactly two docs, one of which is a FAQ, and the second is a CSS customisation manual for very simple stuff. I've gone through them a multitude of times and unfortunately I can't find a reason behind why this is happening. I should point out htaccess was initially .txt and I changed it to .htacess - that's about as much modifying as I did back-end wise.

Comment: You need to change that back if you don't have the third seo option set to yes. Or just change that option to yes.

Comment: @Elin Which ones would you recommend keeping in order to improve my ranking? Also returned it to htaccess.txt and it didn't help :/ I really need this to work (which btw, I massively appreciate all the help thusfar) since it's a client project and I'm basically 99% done with it, minus some aesthetic stuffs.

Comment: It's better to use .htaccess and put yes to the third option; it makes the urls a bit more readable.

Comment: @Elin Done! Any other suggestions with regards to the home page issue?

Comment: I'm still seeing index.php in the urls so I'm not sure what's hapening if you have change the settings. Is there something special with that top menu?

Comment: @Elin You're talking about URL rewriting - that's been causing me 404 errors with anything aside from the homepage, that's why I have it disabled. If you go on now you can see what I mean by that

Comment: Are you using an extension to manage rewriting? Or the core sef? Because if you have rewriting set to use and .htaccess then you should not be getting index.php in  your urls.  But you have some strange urls

Comment: Could you please give me some sort of reference I could compare with the .htaccess I have? Also, could this be the issue causing the action of setting homepages to not work properly?

Comment: The home page url is fine, you can always look at the joomla repository to see what the .htaccess should contain. SOmetimes your hosts may have their own .htaccess in place in which case you should add the joomla part to the current file.

Comment: @Elin Are there any free extensions that carry out the same functionality as the featured articles? Or even the category blog? Because I figured my only workaround would be to have a module on the front page that streamed the latest articles from each category on the site.

Comment: I don't really understand what you're asking for.  IF you want a module for each category do news flash. You should really just fix the template so to does what you want.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like an issue related to whatever is serving your static content.

Apache is the typical server on many shared hosting services. I would first check the document root of your site for the **.htaccess** [hidden] file, and there are any number of things to look out for.

*ie------>*    [magic quotes](http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_turn_off_magic_quotes_gpc_for_Joomla_3),  some other common issues related to .htaccess, rewrites and redirects like;

Allow symlinks(many hosts do not allow this anymore and could be related to the issue. I would speak with my host at that point)

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
```

Rewrites should be on

```
RewriteEngine On
```

Another thing that may be worth trying is renaming the “.htaccess” file ---> “.htaccess~”
And maybe even php.ini (if that is applicable for your version of php) and let apache recreate it.

I would take this information and continue readingh throug the joomla docs in the first link mentioned and come back with more specific questions if you need.

Comment: Well, I tried adding: php_flag magic_quotes_gpc off to my .htaccess as well as a '~' to the end of the file. Yet neither yielded a result :/ I'm on Godaddy if that's any help. RewriteEngine is also already on btw. One last thing worth mentioning is that I have no php.ini file.

The reason my question is unfortunately not as specific as i'd like it to be is that I have no clue what my problem has happened as a result of. I've made no changes to any code, It was all done in the front-end of /administrator/

Comment: @jRadd are you answering in the context of Joomla?

Comment: Yes, this is in the context of Joomla. But more–so towards the context of shared hosting and apache. I don't know a whole lot about joomla, but I have had to troubleshoot it a few times before.